# bison/flex: calculator interprets double values as integers so I added #define YYSTYPE double, but I multiple compilation errors

Tags: c++, parsing, bison, flex-lexer

I am implementing calculator using flex and bison, but double values are interpreted as integers, then I was looking for answers on the internet and I realized the mistake was probably that bison interprets numbers as integers, so if I have input "1.2" in *yylval = atof(yytext) is 1 instead of 1.2. So I tried adding #define YYSTYPE double in parser.ypp but I'm getting compiling errors.
I know there are several similar questions, but none of them really helped me.
Here are my lex and ypp files and compiling errors I get. 
Thanks in advance.

lexer.lex:

```
%option noyywrap
%option noinput
%option nounput

%{
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <string>
    #include <fstream>

    #include "parser.tab.hpp"

%}

%%

[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)? {
    *yylval = atof(yytext);
        return NUMBER;
}



sin {
    return SIN;
}

cos {
    return COS;
}

tan {
    return TG;
}

tg {
    return TG;
}

ctan {
    return CTG;
}

ctg {
    return CTG;
}

asin {
    return ASIN;
}

acos {
    return ACOS;
}

atan {
    return ATG;
}

actan {
    return ACTG;
}

ln {
    return LN;
}

log {
    return LOG;
}

exp {
    return EXP;
}

sqrt {
    return SQRT;
}

abs {
    return ABS;
}

mod {
    return MOD;
}

[a-z] {
    return VARIABLE;
}

[-+*/^()%!,] {
    return *yytext;
}


[ \t\n] ;

. {

}
```

parser.ypp:

```
%{

#define YYSTYPE double


#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

 bool indicator_calculating_value ;

extern int yylex();

void yyerror(double *return_value, std::string s);

%}




%parse-param  { double *return_value}

%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/' '%'
%left SIN COS TG CTG ASIN ACOS ATG ACTG LN LOG MOD
%left UMINUS
%left '^' EXP SQRT
%left ABS
%left '!'


%type <double> E
%token <double> NUMBER
%token <char> VARIABLE;
%start pocetak

%%
pocetak
    : E {
       *return_value = $1;

    };

E   
    : E '+' E {
        if (indicator_calculating_value) {
            $$ = $1 + $3;
        }
    } 
    | E '*' E {

        if (indicator_calculating_value) {
            $$ = $1 * $3;
        }
    }
    | E '-' E {
        if (indicator_calculating_value) {
            $$ = $1 - $3;
        }
    }
    | E '/' E {

        if(indicator_calculating_value) {
            if ($3 == 0) {
                yyerror(0, "divide by zero");
            }
            $$ = $1 / $3;
        }
    }
    | MOD '(' E ',' E ')' {
        if(indicator_calculating_value) {
            if ($5 == 0) {
                yyerror(0, "divide by zero");
            }
            $$ = static_cast<int>($3) % static_cast<int>($5);
        }
    }
    | SIN '(' E ')' {
        if(indicator_calculating_value) {
            $$ = sin($3);
        }
    }
    | COS '(' E ')' {
        if(indicator_calculating_value) {
            $$ = cos($3);
        }
    }
    | TG '(' E ')' {
        if(indicator_calculating_value) {
            $$ = tan($3);
        }
    }
    | CTG '(' E ')' {
        if(indicator_calculating_value) {
            $$ = 1 / tan($3);
        }
    }
    | ASIN '(' E ')' {
        if(indicator_calculating_value) {
            $$ = asin($3);
        }
    }
    | ACOS '(' E ')' {
        if(indicator_calculating_value) {
            $$ = acos($3);
        }
    }       
    | ATG '(' E ')' {
        if(indicator_calculating_value) {
            $$ = atan($3);
        }
    }
    | ACTG '(' E ')' {
        if(indicator_calculating_value) {
            $$ = 1 / atan($3);
        }
    }
    | LN '(' E ')' {
        if(indicator_calculating_value) {
            $$ = log($3);
        }
    }
    | LOG '(' E ',' E ')' {
        if(indicator_calculating_value) {
            $$ = log($5) / log($3);
        }
    }
    | EXP '(' E ')' {
        if(indicator_calculating_value) {
            $$ = exp($3);
        }
    }
    | SQRT '(' E ')' {
        if(indicator_calculating_value) {
            $$ = sqrt($3);
        }
    }
    | E '^' E {
        if(indicator_calculating_value) {
            $$ = pow($1, $3);
        }
    }
    | '-' E %prec UMINUS {
        if(indicator_calculating_value) {
            $$ = -$2;
        }
    } 
    | ABS '(' E ')' {
        if(indicator_calculating_value) {
            $$ = fabs($3);
        }
    }
    | E '!' {
        if(indicator_calculating_value) {
            $$ = 1;
            for (int i = 1; i <= static_cast<int>($1); i++) {
                $$ = $$ * i;
            }
        }
    }
    | '(' E ')' {
        if(indicator_calculating_value) {
            $$ = $2;
        }
    }
    | NUMBER {
        if(indicator_calculating_value) {
            $$ = $1;
        }
    }
    | VARIABLE {

    }
    ;
%%

void yyerror(double *return_value, std::string s)
{
   std::cout << s << std::endl;

}

int main() {

    indicator_calculating_value = true;

    double value = 0.0;
    yyparse(&value);

    std::cout << value << std::endl;



    return 0;
}
```

errors:

```
make
bison -d -v parser.ypp
g++ -Wall -L/usr/local/lib -lmgl-qt5 -lmgl -lm  -c -o parser.tab.o parser.tab.cpp
parser.ypp: In function ‘int yyparse(double*)’:
parser.ypp:42:34: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘double’
        *return_value = $1;
                                  ^     
parser.ypp:42:34: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘double’
parser.ypp:49:20: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘double’
             $$ = $1 + $3;
                    ^~~~~~
parser.ypp:49:20: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘double’
parser.ypp:55:20: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘double’
             $$ = $1 * $3;
                    ^~~~~~
parser.ypp:55:20: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘double’
parser.ypp:60:20: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘double’
             $$ = $1 - $3;
                    ^~~~~~
parser.ypp:60:20: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘double’
parser.ypp:66:27: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘double’
             if ($3 == 0) {
                           ^     
parser.ypp:66:27: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘double’
parser.ypp:69:20: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘double’
             $$ = $1 / $3;
                    ^~~~~~
parser.ypp:69:41: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘double’
             $$ = $1 / $3;
                                         ^     
parser.ypp:69:41: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘double’
parser.ypp:69:68: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
             $$ = $1 / $3;
                                                                    ^
parser.ypp:74:28: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘double’
             if ($5 == 0) {
                            ^     
parser.ypp:74:28: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘double’
parser.ypp:77:20: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘double’
             $$ = static_cast<int>($3) % static_cast<int>($5);
                    ^~~~~~
parser.ypp:77:58: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘double’
             $$ = static_cast<int>($3) % static_cast<int>($5);
                                                          ^~~~  
parser.ypp:77:58: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘double’
parser.ypp:77:105: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
             $$ = static_cast<int>($3) % static_cast<int>($5);
                                                                                                         ^
parser.ypp:77:105: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
parser.ypp:82:20: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘double’
             $$ = sin($3);
                    ^~~~~~
parser.ypp:82:20: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘double’
parser.ypp:87:20: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘double’
             $$ = cos($3);
                    ^~~~~~
parser.ypp:87:20: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘double’
parser.ypp:92:20: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘double’
             $$ = tan($3);
                    ^~~~~~
parser.ypp:92:20: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘double’
parser.ypp:97:20: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘double’
             $$ = 1 / tan($3);
                    ^~~~~~
parser.ypp:97:20: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘double’
parser.ypp:102:20: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘double’
             $$ = asin($3);
                    ^~~~~~
parser.ypp:102:20: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘double’
parser.ypp:107:20: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘double’
             $$ = acos($3);
                    ^~~~~~
parser.ypp:107:20: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘double’
parser.ypp:112:20: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘double’
             $$ = atan($3);
                    ^~~~~~
parser.ypp:112:20: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘double’
parser.ypp:117:20: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘double’
             $$ = 1 / atan($3);
                    ^~~~~~
parser.ypp:117:20: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘double’
parser.ypp:122:20: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘double’
             $$ = log($3);
                    ^~~~~~
parser.ypp:122:20: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘double’
parser.ypp:127:20: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘double’
             $$ = log($5) / log($3);
                    ^~~~~~
parser.ypp:127:20: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘double’
parser.ypp:132:20: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘double’
             $$ = exp($3);
                    ^~~~~~
parser.ypp:132:20: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘double’
parser.ypp:137:20: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘double’
             $$ = sqrt($3);
                    ^~~~~~
parser.ypp:137:20: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘double’
parser.ypp:142:20: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘double’
             $$ = pow($1, $3);
                    ^~~~~~
parser.ypp:142:20: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘double’
parser.ypp:147:20: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘double’
             $$ = -$2;
                    ^~    
parser.ypp:147:20: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘double’
parser.ypp:152:20: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘double’
             $$ = fabs($3);
                    ^~~~~~
parser.ypp:152:20: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘double’
parser.ypp:157:20: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘double’
             $$ = 1;
                    ^     
parser.ypp:157:20: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘double’
parser.ypp:158:62: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘double’
             for (int i = 1; i <= static_cast<int>($1); i++) {
                                                              ^     
parser.ypp:158:62: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘double’
parser.ypp:158:70: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
             for (int i = 1; i <= static_cast<int>($1); i++) {
                                                                      ^
parser.ypp:159:24: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘double’
                 $$ = $$ * i;
                        ^~~~~ 
parser.ypp:159:24: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘double’
parser.ypp:165:20: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘double’
             $$ = $2;
                    ^     
parser.ypp:165:20: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘double’
parser.ypp:170:20: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘double’
             $$ = $1;
                    ^     
parser.ypp:170:20: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘double’
Makefile:15: recipe for target 'parser.tab.o' failed
make: *** [parser.tab.o] Error 1
```

Comment: On a couple of notes unrelated to the errors you get, I suggest you read the generated header file `"parser.tab.hpp"`, because then you will see that `yylval` isn't a pointer. Also the libraries you link with should be *last* on the command-line when you build (or at least after all source and object files), and you don't need to add linker-libraries when generating object files.

Answer (score 2):

Your bison file defines symbols wirh two different types:

```
%type <double> E
%token <double> NUMBER
%token <char> VARIABLE;
```

(The semicolon at the end of the third line there is incorrect, although I think bison will just ignore it.)

As discussed in the [bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Multiple-Types), the most common way of accomplishing that is with a `%union` bison declaration, which will declare `YYSTYPE` to be a C union. That's not compatible with using the preprocessor to `#define YYSTYPE` as a single type.

If you use a `%union` declaration, you specify a C type and a tag for each variant of `YYSTYPE`. What you then place between the angle brackets is the *tag*, not the type. For example,

```
%union {
     double number;
     char id;
}
%token <number> NUMBER
```

With that declaration, bison will declare a `union` type with two members named `number` and `id`. And it will automatically make `$n` refer to the correct member (if the symbol `$n` refers to has a known type) by appending a member selector. In other words, if `$1` refers to a `NUMBER`, bison will replace it in the generated code with something like `stack[top - 2 + 1].number`. (Without the `%union` and type declaration, the replacement would have been something like `stack[top - 2 + 1]`.)

Bison doesn't require you to use a `%union`. If you don't and you still declare types for your tokens and non-terminals, bison will assume you know what you're doing and that you have somehow declared `YYSTYPE` as a composite type. It will do exactly the same replacement, adding a member selector to the references to stack values with known types.

So in your case, you've declared `%type <double> E`, so bison will replace a `$1` in an action where the `$1` refers to the symbol `E` with something like `stack[top - 4 + 1].double`.

Of course, that will cause the compiler to choke. `double` is a reserved word and cannot be used as a composite member name, and anyway `YYSTYPE` is a scalar (a `double`) because that's the way you defined it.

You haven't yet tried to compile your scanner, but you will encounter similar problems there. Obviously, `YYSTYPE` must be the same type in both the scanner and the parser, which are separate C translation units. If you had used a `%union` declaration, bison would have put the C `union` into tje generated header, which you `#include` in the generated scanner. That guarantees consistency. If you don't use `%union`, then you have to make sure that the scanner has the right definition.

Since you don't do anything in your flex file to declare `YYSTYPE`, the generated code will fallback to `int`. It does this by including a block like this:

```
#ifndef YYSTYPE
#define YYSTYPE int
#endif
```

The bison manual contains lots of simple examples. There are a lot more options than I have presented here, and you would be well-advised to spend a bit of time reading the manual.

Comment: Thank you. First I used union, and it worked in terminal, but since it doesn't work in Qt (works only in debug mode, weird), I tried to change my lexer and parser but failed, as you see.

Comment: @baksuz: I have no idea what Qt has to do with anything, and I obviously can't see how your attempt with `union` failed. Or even what you mean by "doesn't work". Feel free to ask a new question, but please cut your code down to the minimum required to see the problem, as explained in the SO help page on [mre]. There are other problems with your code. It's always good to start with a very small subset of what you want to do and gradually add more features. That way, you can get each little part working without confusion.